# How to bypass the error DbUpdateConcurrencyException when trying to add or update nested object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When i try to update or add a entity with a nested child i get this error following the put logic i put in place.

Why do i get this error: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCart(string id, ProductsInCart productInCart)
        {
            var cart = _context.Cart.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

            var product= cart.CartItems?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Product.Id.Equals(productInCart.Product.Id));
            if (product != null)
            {
                product.Quantity += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cart.CartItems = new List<ProductsInCart>(){ productInCart };
            }
            _context.Entry(cart).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CartExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Here are the objects:

```
public class Cart
    {
        public string  Id { get; set; }
        public List<ProductsInCart> CartItems { get; set; }

    }

    public class ProductsInCart
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(10000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: nobody ever tries to read exception messages :( there is a [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962) that answer your question

Answer (score 0):

> This error usually occurs when there is a change in the properties of
>   a record in the current version and its database version.

According to the code, the only value changed is the `Quantity` property.
Check this property in the `ProductsInCart` table.
Also if you use ef type cnfiguration, check if quantity is not contribute in concurrency check.

Concurrency check with fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductsInCart>()
        .Property(p => p.Quantity)
        .IsConcurrencyToken();
}
```

and data annotation

```
[ConcurrencyCheck]
public string Quantity{ get; set; }
```

Also, maybe concurrency check is enabled on other feild

Comment: Hi, for me the productInCart or product are not even in the database, i was thinking that adding them in the cart will automatiqualy add them in the db, at least thats what i read, for the moment it doesnt go in the quantity loop but in the else.